# How to convert to logarithmic scale and back?

Tags: python-3.x, math, floating-point

```py
import math

def log_n_back(x, base):
  return math.pow(math.log(x, base), base)

x = 14
y = log_n_back(x, math.e)
print(y) # 13.983525601880974

y = log_n_back(x, 10)
print(y) # 3.9113921541997523
```

The one using `math.e` at least approximates the answer. But the one using `10` is just wrong.

Further context: I have to work with numbers between `1,000` and `100,000`.

Comment: Why not `math.pow(base, math.log(x, base))`? That's more in line with how logarithms are defined.  Supposing you are working with positive numbers.

Comment: Thank you @JohanC.

Comment: Yeah, the first one only “worked” by coincidence: ln 14 = 2.6390573296152584 is close enough to *e* = 2.718281828459045 that putting the arguments in the wrong order only slightly changed the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the order of the arguments to `pow()`:

```
return math.pow(base, math.log(x, base))
```

Then it will do what you *intended* it to do, and results will be very much closer to what you want.

Comment: Limited, of course, by float precision... `math.pow(10, math.log(14, 10))` will not *quite* equal 14...